# Mounted disk have 100% disk space usage but system do have enough space

Tags: mount

I have mounted a box on my Linux system , it is successfully mounted but i can not create any file inside my mounted folder.

getting space issue while creating file.

```
vulnix@kali:/var/www/mnt$ mkdir ssh
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘ssh’: No space left on device
```

df -h

```
vulnix@kali:/var/www/mnt$ df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        304M  5.7M  298M   2% /run
/dev/sda1                     77G   14G   59G  20% /
tmpfs                        1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                        1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                        304M   12K  304M   1% /run/user/135
tmpfs                        304M   48K  304M   1% /run/user/0
192.168.59.143:/home/vulnix  774M  772M     0 100% /var/www/mnt
```

df -i

```
    vulnix@kali:/var/www/mnt$ df -i
Filesystem                   Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev                         208001    380  207621    1% /dev
tmpfs                        214748    771  213977    1% /run
/dev/sda1                   5111808 543587 4568221   11% /
tmpfs                        214748      1  214747    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        214748      3  214745    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                        214748     16  214732    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                        214748     23  214725    1% /run/user/135
tmpfs                        214748     36  214712    1% /run/user/0
192.168.59.143:/home/vulnix   49728  33186   16542   67% /var/www/mnt
```

I don't understand whats wrong with my mounted folder .

Comment: Do not post links to images of text.  Post the text directly.

Comment: @AndrewHenle thx

Comment: `/var/www/mnt` is 100% used? So it's full.

Comment: @Halfgaar That's what my problem is.